# Ember Data: CreateRecord not updating model when using store.find with query params

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When my route model uses `this.store.find('user')` it updates automatically and the template shows new records created using `createRecord`.  So the following works as expected:

Route:

```
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
```

Template:

```
{{#each user in model}}
      {{user.username}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

Controller Code:

```
  // Triggered when form submitted to create a new user
  var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
    username: this.get('username').trim()
  });
  // new user shows up in template immediately after createRecord
```

If I change my route model to use the query params version of `find` the template no longer updates when I do a `createRecord`

Route:

```
  model: function(){
    // query params version of store.find
    return this.store.find('user', {enabledOnly: false, limit: 100});
  }
```

Controller Code:

```
  // Triggered when form submitted to create a new user
  var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
    username: this.get('username').trim()
  });
  // new user does not show up in template at all
```

It seems like this might be a bug as the only change in the code is switching from the basic `find('user')` to the version that has query params.  Is this expected behavior for ember data?  Why would the model not update the template after `createRecord` is called when the query param version of find is used (i.e., `find('user', {})`)

I was able to create a jsbin that demonstrates the issue.

> http://jsbin.com/kilaridoso/2/edit?html,js,output

Thank you!

I am using the following version:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember             : 1.11.1
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember Data        : 1.0.0-beta.16.1
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: jQuery            : 1.11.3
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 0.8.0-beta.2
ember.debug.js:5197DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking this was a bug I posted over on Ember-Data's GitHUB page.  The answer provided is that this is expected behavior.  Here is the full response from wecc (thanks!)

> Using store.find(type, query) does not return a live RecordArray so
>   the behavior you're describing is correct.
>
> You should be able to use store.filter(type, query, filter) (docs)
>   instead.
>
> The reason for store.find(type, query) not updating with the newly
>   created record is that query is just sent to the server, there's no
>   way for ED to know if new records "match" that query or not. Sometimes
>   the query might be a simple filter like { isUnread: true } but it can
>   also be something like { since: '2015-05-10 10:51' }. Using
>   store.filter(type, query, filter) on the other hand, passing both
>   query and a filter callback function, ED can pass query to the server
>   and use the filter function on all new records to know if it's to be
>   included in the live RecordArray or not.

Here is a link to the answer:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3057

Comment: No longer a valid answer as filter is being deprecated.

Comment: @Epirocks.. Any solution for this issue? I am also using store.query to get some meta info with the records array. But my view is not updating, If I add a new record..

Comment: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/query-params/ check "opting into a full transition"